# Setting session in php from value being set in the page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, session

I'm trying to set a php session onload

```
 $_SESSION["tusername"] = $_POST['ttuser'];
```

however my value is being set in jQuery on `$(function() {`

```
 $('#ttuser').val(tusername);
```

When the page is loaded, the session is not set as I believe the session is being set before the textbox value is set by jQuery. I tried using ajax to post a value to the page, but it doesn't retrieve it.

The only way I am setting the session now is on a button click, the exact same way.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance

**EDIT**
Here is the Function at the start where everything is set, as requested

```
$(function() {
  // Initialize. If we are already logged in, there is no
  // need for the connect button
  Twitch.init({clientId: CLIENT_ID}, function(error, status) {
    if (status.authenticated) {
      // we're logged in :)


      $('.authenticatedd').removeClass('hidden');
    } else {
      $('.welcometitle').html('<strong>Not yet connected with Twitch?</strong>');

      // Show the twitch connect button
      $('.authenticate').removeClass('hidden');
    }
  });


var token = Twitch.getToken();
      $('.twitch-connect').click(function() {
        Twitch.login({
          scope: ['user_read', 'channel_read', 'channel_editor', 'channel_commercial', 'user_subscriptions', 'channel_check_subscription']
        });
      })

Twitch.api({method: 'channel'}, function(error, channel) {
      $('#streamkey').text(channel.stream_key);
    });


    Twitch.api({method: 'user'}, function(error, user) {
    var tusername = user.display_name;
    var tlogo = user.logo;
    $('#twitchname').text(tusername);
    $('#ttuser').val(tusername);
$.get("setsession.php?ttuser="+tusername, function(){

});
    console.log(tlogo);

    if (tlogo != null)
    $('#twitchlogo').attr('src', tlogo);
$.cookie('logo', tlogo, { expires: 14, path: '/'});

    $('.sidename').html('<strong>' + tusername + '</strong> Logged in');
    var currentdate = new Date(); 
    var datetime = currentdate.getHours() + ":" + currentdate.getMinutes() + ":" + currentdate.getSeconds();    
    var items = [];
 items.push('<li><div class="xe-comment-entry"><div class="xe-comment"><a href="#" class="xe-user-name"><span class="label label-success">Status</span></a><p><span class="label label-danger">' +datetime+ '</span> Logged in</p></div></div></li>')
 $('#eventlog').prepend( items.join('') );
    });
```

});

Comment: Can you please clarify yourself a bit more. As what you want to achieve, And what have you tried, And what are to problems.

Comment: We do not have enough of your code in order to be able to make a reasoned guess.

Comment: Basically, I have a page called 'status.php', and when logging in, a variable is being set to a div tag value when the page loads. I am trying to set a session variable to that value. However, I think that the session is being set to null before the text value is set to the div tag.

Comment: From where (a **variable** is being set to a div tag value ) thi variable is coming?

Comment: It is coming from here ->
Twitch.api({method: 'user'}, function(error, user) {
        var tusername = user.display_name;
        var tlogo = user.logo;
         $('#twitchname').text(tusername);
         $('#ttuser').val(tusername);
....

Comment: Can you please update your question with this `Twitch.api` code. It will make it readable.

Comment: Have updated my question

Comment: Where is `$_SESSION["tusername"] = $_POST['ttuser'];` placed? Don't see it in the code. You MUST sent headers (like cookie for session) BEFORE the http body.

Comment: Its currently done on click in the php code -> 
session_start();
if ($_POST["cpoll"]) {
  $_SESSION["tusername"] = $_POST['ttuser'];

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why dont you just make a request to a php file which will initiate the session.

**myfile.php**

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION["tusername"] = $_REQUEST['ttuser'];
echo "Session is : "+$_SESSION["tusername"];
?>
```

**HTML**

```
$(function(){
$.get("myfile.php?ttuser="+tusername, function(data){
console.log(data);
});
 $('#ttuser').val(tusername);
});
```

Comment: I tried that and it echoes the session name here http://dashboard.aotikbot.tv/setsession.php?ttuser=username but when I check for the session on another page, it doesn't read it

Comment: Are they on same domain?

Comment: yes they are. I put $.get("myfile.php?ttuser="+tusername, function(){
}); in the Twitch.api function if thats right?

Comment: Ooh, I see what its doing now, think you misunderstood. I need 'tusername' to be set as the session as it is secure and can't be changed. I just need the session to be set when status.php is loaded

Comment: It is being set here with the Twitch API on login var tusername = user.display_name;

Comment: I have actually found a way with this code -> $.post('/setsession.php', { 'tusername' : 'sessionvariablename', 'value' : getname}); and it works! Anyway thanks for your time, appreciate it ;)

Comment: That means the PHP file you were having had `$_POST`. Anyways If it solves your problem please consider voting it up and marking it as correct answer.

Comment: I had GET before but changed it! Will do!